# Why does strategy pattern use implements instead extends?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Why does the strategy pattern make use of `implements` instead of `extends`? Because I would assume that StrategyA `is-a` StrategyBase, which would rather lead me to extending the base strategy than implementing it as an interface.

So, would it be wrong to apply the strategy pattern with "extends"? And what are advantages if I'm using it with interface?

Comment: Because you don't need implementation inheritance? `implements` also declares  an "is-a" relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no common code to put into your strategy base type, you are achieving nothing by using an abstract class instead of an interface, except for constraining the clients of such API to using a dedicated class for the strategy, where they would perhaps want a single class implement several interfaces.

Comment: Strongly agree. Both Interface and Class denote a type, and strategies will have a common type. The only difference is whether you want to add some common functionality or behavior to the type, but that's an implementation decision.

Answer (score 1):

as per my info : using `extends` , you will not be able to extend any other class.
and if not definition is required for methods why not to used `interface`.